# Accessing an array inside an array in json response

Tags: android, jsonresponse

I'm using the below code to take the values of price. I can get the value for price. However, when it comes to crust it runs to the exception.

```
@Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            List<String> crust = new ArrayList<String>();   
            List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
                        && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1")) {
                    Log.i("Price ", object.getString("Price"));
                    price.add(object.getString("Price"));
                    Log.i("Crust ", object.getString("Crust"));
                    crust.add(object.getString("Crust"));

                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this is the json response

```
{  
      "Category":"1PI",
      "Price":0.0000,
      "SubCategoryID":1,
      "SubMenu":true,
      "SubMenuEntity":[  
         {  
            "Crust":"Sausage",
```

Crust is positioned in, array inside an array, how can i access crust in my above coding.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: **"Crust is positioned in, array inside an array"** : No, Crust is in a JSON object in a JSON array which is in a JSON object. All you need to do is get the value of the `SubMenuEntity` (the JSON array) and get the JSON object(s) it contains and then get the value of the Crust name/value pair.

Comment: Get jsonArray from your object and get Crust from that array.
I'd reccomend you to use GSON on parsing json responses, also it's better to use a JSON library in your project like retrofit both for performance & manageability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*SubMenuEntity* item has an array of objects. You need to get the array and loop though it. For each object, get the value of *Crust*.

```
try {
      List<String> crust = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();

      JSONArray responseJson = null;

      for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
        JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

        if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
            && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1")) {
          Log.i("Price ", object.getString("Price"));
          price.add(object.getString("Price"));

          JSONArray subMenuArray = object.getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");
          for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
            JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray.getJSONObject(j);
            Log.i("Crust ", subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));
            crust.add(subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));
          }

        }

      }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your `Crust` is inside `SubMenuEntity`, you shoud get this using [object.getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity")](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29) and then get `Crust` from first `Object` in this array